# Railo Custom 505 handler and ajax pathing

Tags: ajax, error-handling, relative-path, railo, cfc

I have an external javascript file that calls a setinterval function that checks a cfc for file transfer completion between server and a remote computer.  When I call this function with standard error handler it works.  Soon as I add the custom error handler it fails.  Im dumb founded.

```
    File_transfer.js   
    {
        Function check_stream_server ()    
        Ajax call to query, application scoped, query-object.  
        Path = "ss_check.cfc"
        };
        // exception log and response with custom error
        // I work with no custom error handler

    Function send_file ()
    {
      Ajax to Put file in object; // I work
      Same ajax call to Start stream.   
     thread if not running; //I work
     Setinterval (check_stream_server,       5000) //I set interval 
     }

    }
}
    Index.cfm null   {
      Include the file_transfer.js
    <button>click </button>

    <script>
    Button.on ('click', function (){
     Send_file()
     })
     </script>
    }
```

Index.cfm, check_ss.cfc, and the object_insert.cfc are all in same folder.  Js is in external lib folder.

Sorry that this code sucks but I'm typing this from phone and won't be able to sleep tonight or be dreaming about it all night.

If it helps I'm also running a compiled archive.

Comment: You should be applauded for typing all of that on your phone, but I have no clue what you're asking!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in setting the cf admin on update error.  There was a remote clients = arrayofclients that was not removed from someone copying and pasting the example in the docs.  I had a work around that worked by initializing the functions into the proper scopes in the initial cfm page, but later found out it was a bug when setting the custom error handler